# document.createElement returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, vaadin, vaadin8

I work on a Vaadin 8-based application. In a couple of hard-to-characterize scenarios - and I haven't been able to isolate the triggering factor - `document.createElement` starts to return `undefined` on all calls. This has been seen in both IE11 and Chrome (but in different circumstances in each case). My first theory was that it might be a browser out-of-memory issue, but I created a scenario with many more DOM elements that did not reproduce the error, and memory profiling showed no notable spike in memory usage at the point the problem happens. Also, when it happens it's at a predictable point in time - not random enough to be that sort of environmental issue.

When the problem happens, the console reports an odd status for the `document.createElement` function - it looks 'broken', but doesn't appear that it's just been clobbered by another function or something. Following is what the console shows under normal circumstances:

[image: Normal createElement in IE11]

...while this is what shows after the problem occurs (plus a reference to a nonexistent attribute on document, to illustrate the difference between that and what `createElement` shows):

[image: Broken createElement in IE11]

In Chrome the behavior in the console is similar:

[image: Broken createElement in Chrome]

Has anybody seen such a symptom in any browser and/or have any insight in tracking down the cause?

EDIT 17 January 2018: When I originally wrote this I only witnessed the problem behavior in IE11. Since then I have seen the same behavior under a different circumstance in Chrome.

Comment: Any chance of a  [mcve]?

Comment: @mplungjan - I fear not; my whole challenge is around characterizing this issue. I can't even reproduce on my development instance - it's only seen in production for a specific client's environment which I can't replicate.

Comment: I try to make a test with Document.CreateElement in IE 11. In normal conditions, It is working fine and I did not get any undefined error. If you post a sample code and steps than we can try to make a test again. Which can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: What does `document.createElement.toString()` show when it looks broken?

Comment: @Ry- In Chrome, `document.createElement.toString()` returns `undefined`. When I just reproduced in IE, unlike previously `document.createElement` shows 'normal' output even though calling it returns `undefined`. Calling `document.createElement.toString()` is showing `"function createElement() { [native code] }"` (spaced across multiple lines).

Comment: Pretty weird. When it’s broken, what does `document.hasOwnProperty('createElement')` return?

Comment: @Ry- Great idea! `document.hasOwnProperty('createElement')` returns `true` in both IE and Chrome when the problem occurs. If I `delete document.createElement`, it starts working again. So - something somewhere is shadowing it. Now to track that down...

Comment: @Aron: `{ const orig = document.createElement; Object.defineProperty(document, 'createElement', {configurable: true, get: () => orig, set(value) { debugger; }}); }` might help? (It won’t if whatever defines it uses `Object.defineProperty` as well, though – in that case, there’s a chance you can get an error to reach you by removing `configurable: true`.)

Comment: @Ry- thanks again - I used the break-on-access library to do essentially that, and discovered it's some injected analytics or security or who-knows-what Enterprisey code that I wasn't even aware of. So, mystery solved! If you'd like to create an answer outlining your extremely helpful debugging tips, I'd be more than happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was that `document.createElement` was being replaced by some (buggy) injected anti-phishing JS I wasn't aware of. The problem with that JS is outside the scope of this question, but debugging tips provided in comments on the question were valuable in tracking it down:

1. The fact that `document.createElement` was being shadowed was discovered by noting that `document.hasOwnProperty('createElement')` returned `true`.
2. Defining a setter function for `document.createElement` that triggers the debugger helped me track down the offending code. I used the [break-on-access](https://github.com/paulirish/break-on-access) snippet for this purpose, but also see simple code in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54204934/document-createelement-returning-undefined?noredirect=1#comment95316857_54204934) above for a roll-your-own alternative.